# Simple docker-compose to execute a Jar

Tags: java, docker, jar, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a very simple Docker container, that will execute a Jar file.  I want an image that will run a simple Jar.  I dont need anything else special.

So far my docker-compose.yml looks like this, but it doesn't start correctly:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  myapp:
    image: openjdk:8
    container_name: "myapp"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    volumes:
      - "./meanwhile-in-hell.jar:/app.jar"
    command: ['java', '-jar', '/app.jar']
```

```
STATUS
Restarting (1) 2 seconds ago
```

Using the `command: ['java', '-jar', '/app.jar']` option, I see this in the Docker logs:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

If I change to use `entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "java  -jar /app.jar" ]`, I see the same error.

The Jar file is absolutely fine and not corrupt.  I have run it manually on another `tomcat:8-alpine` container I have running and it starts up successfully.

Comment: Volume will help you to map a volume to a volume or map a folder from your host into your container as a volume so you might need to update it a bit to make it work. `- ".:/usr/app"` and then your command: `command: ['java', '-jar', '/usr/app/meanwhile-in-hell.jar']`, give it a try